# Performance degradation in hibernate SessionImpl get(Class<T> entityClass, Serializable id) method in 5.2.5.version compared to 3.6.10

Tags: hibernate, java-8, jboss7.x, hibernate-mapping, jboss6.x

We have upgraded our application from old stack to new stack.

**Old Stack**

- Java 6
- Jboss-eap-6.4
- Hibernate-core : 3.6.10.Final

**New Stack**

- Java 8
- Jboss-eap-7.0
- Hibernate-core : 5.2.5.Final

We have seen a performance degradation for **org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(Class, Serializable) SessionImpl.java** method in new stack. We used to call this method for the persistent instance of the given entity class.

**Code**

```
public <T extends SuperJDOIfc> T getEntityFromReferenceCache(Serializable primaryKey, Class<T> entityClass, SessionImpl sessImpl) {
        SuperBasicReferenceJDOIfc jdoIfc = null;
        org.hibernate.annotations.Cache cacheAnn = entityClass.getAnnotation(org.hibernate.annotations.Cache.class);
        if (cacheAnn != null && EhcacheManager.REFERENCE.equals(cacheAnn.region())) {
            if (sessImpl != null && !sessImpl.isClosed()) {
                jdoIfc = (SuperBasicReferenceJDOIfc) sessImpl.get(entityClass, primaryKey);
            }
```

Calling code : **sessImpl.get(entityClass, primaryKey)**
[/details]

We did profiling from yourkit for both the stack and we found below timings:

**NEW stack**: For 3714 entity it's around **20 sec**.
**OLD stack**: For 3762 entity it's around **2 sec**.

How to solve this performance issue. Is there any configuration we need to do or is it a bug ?

PS: Same code is used in both stack.

Thanks.

Comment: ? so the newstack is faster ? do you have typo ?

Comment: Sorry..It's typo...Newstack is slower. Corrected POST. Thank you

Comment: Hi Ken..Any idea on this??

Comment: no idea.i suggest you use flamegraph to find out which part of the codes spend most of the time